# ORA-00979: NOT A GROUP BY Expression Working with Dates in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a Date datatype column named sDateTime, I want the data to be selected grouped by dates, in fact I want to show the sales sum of every day of a particular month.

The sDateTime is of Date datatype but it also stores time with it so I need to convert it into only date format. I'm using the following query which throws an exception **ORA-00979** Anyone please help me with this.

```
SELECT sdatetime   AS Sale_Date,
       SUM(amount) AS Sale
FROM   sales
GROUP  BY To_char(sdatetime, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
HAVING sdatetime BETWEEN To_date('2015-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND
                         To_date('2015-01-09', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-write the query like this

```
select to_char(sDateTime,'yyyy-MM-dd') AS Sale_Date, SUM(Amount) AS Sale 
FROM SALES  where sDateTime between to_date('2015-01-01','yyyy-MM-dd')
     and to_date('2015-01-09','yyyy-MM-dd') 
GROUP BY to_char(sDateTime,'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Comment: PriNceKhAn, you have to thank @Exhausted. I have just formatted answer :)